# Amazon s3 video is not played on Iphone

Tags: reactjs, iphone, video

I am having a react website where on the home page I have used the Video tag to play the video. On android browser the video is getting played but on Iphone browser the video is not getting played and s3 call from browser is not shown in the network call fro iphone i have checked using browserstack iphone emulator. Below is my code.

```
<video
    ref={videoRef}
    playsInline={true}
    controls={false}
    className={style.videoPlayer}
    loop={true}
    muted={true}
    onLoadedData={() => {
        const promise = videoRef.current.play();
        if (promise !== undefined) {
           promise
             .then(() => {
                videoRef.current.play();
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                videoRef.current.muted();
              });
          }
        }}
      >
       <source
         src="https://ibeng.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/ibEngHeroVideo+(1).mp4"
         type="video/mp4"
         />
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
```

please help me with this issue.

Comment: Fix it by putting your MP4 metadata at the front. Use a tool like FFmpeg with option **fast start** to fix the MP4 file header in few seconds, then re-upload the fixed file to AWS. PS: Metadata is needed to know what/where is frame 1 etc... MP4 can have metadata at the front or at the back of the file. Your MP4 has got its data at the back, so any app must first fully download before it can play (but Chrome is quickly jumping to the back, to check the metadata).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should replace onLoadData to onClick as IOS devices / IOS browsers need interaction to play a video. They dont let video to autoplay.

IOS has strict autoplay policies, please have a look at their webkit page.

Properly handle this promise

```
 const video = videoRef.current;
    if (video.paused) {
      video.play().catch((err) => {
        console.error("Autoplay error:", err);
      });
    } else {
      video.pause();
    }
```